# Importing metadata from HTML into ArcCatalog fails

Tags: arccatalog, metadata

I downloaded restricted areas shapefile from here:

https://webgis.dme.qld.gov.au/webgis/webqmin/viewer.htm

It came with a rst.html file, which, on opening, displayed a page exactly the same as the 'Description' tab in ArcCatalog. Enthused, I imported this file into ArcCatalog, hoping it would transfer all the information automatically. Unfortunately, however, it only imported the bounding box coordinates and put the name of the shapefile as the heading.

Anyone know what went wrong?

Wil

Comment: Did the shapefile download include an XML file?

Comment: No, it did not. I have since requested that the administrators of that webGIS include a XML metadata file along with all downloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't import metadata from HTML files*, it must be XML. See [Import Metadata (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Import_Metadata/00120000000w000000/).

> - Text or HTML files containing metadata can't be imported.

*If the HTML was generated by the [USGS `mp` tool](http://geology.usgs.gov/tools/metadata/) it may be possible to [convert it to text with other tools](http://geology.usgs.gov/tools/metadata/tools/doc/opinion/cns-again.html) and then to XML with mp. For more information see [Importing metadata](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Importing_metadata/00120000004q000000/).